# "error: warnings found and -Werror specified" on gerrit

Tags: jenkins, gerrit

We use `Jenkins` and `Gerrit` for Continuous Integration and review process.

Currently, the builds are failing with below error.

```
error: warnings found and -Werror specified
```

In `Gerrit` logs i see only warnings. We expect that build should not break on warnings.

Can someone suggest the possible configuration mistake here.

P.S. I went through other related questions but they aren't helping much.

Comment: How are you building your project? Assuming Maven can you post the compiler configuration from your pom.xml?

Comment: Its `ant` and unfortunately I don't have access to any files on main server. But if I could know the root cause/configuration change, I can ask someone with access to make changes in files.

Comment: My guess at the root cause is that the configuration for your java compiler has -Werror enabled. That error is emitted by the java compiler when the -Werror option is enabled during compilation. It should be obvious in the build logs where the error is occurring and that should help your build engineer figure out where the compiler configuration is being set.